# Exception using Transformer and PowerMockRunner

Tags: java, xml, string, dom, powermock

I want to convert Document to String. I'm using the following method:

```
public static String toString(Document doc) {
    try {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
        String writerAsString = sw.toString();
        return writerAsString;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error converting to String", ex);
    }
}
```

The code is working fine, but when I run tests and define @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) I get an error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think PowerMockRunner is bringing a transitive dependency that overrides the one that you normally use at runtime. You may want to do a dependency-tree on the project, check what is the guilty double dependency and exclude it explicitly from the dependency to power mockito.

Comment: Can anyone provide an example on how to fix this? I've tried to include exclusions for  org.objenesis, but is makes no difference.